# Как реализовать замкнутый массив на C++?

Tags: математика, массивы, c++

Необходимо реализовать на C++ такой массив, например размерности 4 (с индексами 0 1 2 3), чтобы в дальнейшем при обращении к несуществующему элементу 4 программа выдавала значение с индексом 0.

Как это реализовать с условием ясно — нужно выразить доступ к элементам с помощью формулы.

Возможно некорректно поставлен вопрос, но в итоге нужна заготовка программы, которая должна создать двумерный массив, замкнутый по всем концам (как в фигуре Тор), для того, чтобы в дальнейшем реализовать определение покрытий для карты Карно.

Comment: не сочтите за придирку, но тэг "замыкание" у вас совершенно не к месту. На самом деле он означает [кое-что][1] другое

[1]:http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Comment: Обычно в таком случае говорят "циклический", "кольцевой" или "закольцованный"  массив (вектор, список).

Также эти термины часто используют для буферов и кэшей.

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Для неотрицательных значений:**

```
const int SIZE = 4;
int a[SIZE];
for(int i=0;i<15;i++) cout << a[i%SIZE] << " ";
```

% — остаток от деления, значения 0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,...

**Для отрицательных значений:**

ряд чисел которые мы должны преобразовать:

-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5...

Что мы должны получить (для SIZE=4):

3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1...

Вышеуказанный способ нам выдаст следующие значения:

-1,0,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,0,1...

Мы можем ко всем этим значениям прибавить SIZE, и тогда у нас все значения будут положительными, и вторично берем по модулю:

```
for(int i=-5;i<=5;i++)
{
    j=( (i%SIZE) + SIZE )%SIZE;
    cout << a[j] << " ";
}
```

**Для упрощения понимания кода:**
чтобы в коде часто не встречались непонятные формулы, используйте функцию (или макрос), которая будет преобразовывать индексы.

Например макрос:

```
#define GetIndex(_index,_size) ( ( (_index%_size) + _size )%_size )
```

Для двумерного случая:

```
const int X_SIZE = 4;
const int Y_SIZE = 10;
int a[X_SIZE][Y_SIZE];
cin >> x >> y;
cout << a[GetIndex(x,X_SIZE)][GetIndex(y,Y_SIZE)];
```

Comment: У вас два деления, наверное, лучше свести к одному:

    inline int GetIndex(int index, int size)
    {
        int result = index % size;
        if (result < 0) result += size;
        return result;
    }

Comment: Большое спасибо, за оперативный ответ. Теперь все идеально работает!

Answer (score 0):

Согласен, наследование от `std::vector` не самая лучшая идея и `CyclicArray` нужно использовать с осторожностью.

```
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class CyclicArray : public std::vector<T> {
 public:
  typedef typename std::vector<T>::size_type UnsignedIndex;
  typedef typename std::make_signed<UnsignedIndex>::type SignedIndex;

  using std::vector<T>::vector;

  T& operator[](SignedIndex index) {
    return GetElement(index);
  }

  const T& operator[](SignedIndex index) const {
    return GetElement(index);
  }

private:
  T& GetElement(SignedIndex index) {
    return std::vector<T>::operator[](NormalizeIndex(index));
  }

  const T& GetElement(SignedIndex index) const {
    return std::vector<T>::operator[](NormalizeIndex(index));
  }

  UnsignedIndex NormalizeIndex(SignedIndex index) {
    auto size = std::vector<T>::size();
    SignedIndex res = (index % size);
    if (res < 0) {
      res += size;
    }
    return static_cast<UnsignedIndex>(res);
  }
};

int main() {
  CyclicArray<int> a{1, 2, 3, 4};
  for (int i = -8; i < 9; ++i) {
    std::cout << i << ": " << a[i] << std::endl;
  }
  // 2-Dimensional
  CyclicArray<CyclicArray<int>> b{{1, 2, 3, 4},
                                  {5, 6, 7, 8},
                                  {9, 10, 11, 12},
                                  {13, 14, 15, 16}};
  for (int i = -4; i < 4; ++i) {
    for (int j = -4; j < 4; ++j) {
      std::cout << i << ", " << j << ": " << b[i][j] << std::endl;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: А теперь сравните Вашу простыню с

    #define GetIndex(_index,_size) ( ( (_index%_size) + _size )%_size )

(только `_index` и `_size` не мешает заключить в скобки)



или м.б. лучше `static inline size_t GetIndex()` от @VladD.


--

Надеюсь вопрос, как **реально** стоит писать, у кучи народа отпадет.

Comment: а почему бы не сделать вектор приватным полем? И сразу класс стал бы хорошим. А то найдется человек, который `at` напишет и ... или итераторы... Хотя с цикличесим массивом итераторы должны работать весело:)

И регистр букв в самом начале уменьшить хорошо было бы.

Comment: У `std::vector` нету виртуального деструктора, так что наследоваться от него нежелательно. В любом случае, идея жёсткой типизации зачётна, +1.

---
Таки-да, вместо наследования лучше композиция. Правда, придётся пробрасывать операции, но вы ведь пишете контейнер, кто сказал, что должно быть легко?

Comment: @avp, простыня лежит себе спокойно в хедере и никого не трогает, а вот

    a[GetIndex(x,X_SIZE)][GetIndex(y,Y_SIZE)]

по всему коду мне кажется намного большей проблемой.

Comment: @KoVadim, согласен, композиция была бы уместнее, но так мы теряем все бесчисленные полезные конструкторы и методы вектора (или все их переписываем)

Comment: @avp: а кому какое дело, как реализовано внутри? Наше дело — сложность использования уменьшать. `GetIndex` обязан быть внутренней функцией, а то кто-то закеширует неправильный `size`.

---
А с макросами снова и снова натыкаться на подводные камни типа `GetIndex(currIndex + 1, size)` (видите, во что это развернётся?) уже давно не смешно.

Comment: @dzhioev: зато можно избавиться от `push_back` и `erase` (наверное), т.к. с циклическим буфером фиксированной длины они явно избыточны и опасны.

Comment: @dzhioev

- От `C++11` здесь только `auto` и `initializer list'ы`. А вот `operator[] const`, кстати говоря, должен возвращать `constexpr`.

- Но это все не так важно, потому что сама идея наследования `CyclicArray` от `std::vector` — это **адовая жесть.** Представьте себе, что экземпляр `CyclicArray<T>` передается в функцию, которая принимает `const std::vector<T>&`, и в этой функции вперемешку используются `operator[]` и вызовы `at().` Одни из них приводят к одному поведению, вторые — ко второму. Похожих кейсов, скорее всего, можно придумать достаточно много.

Comment: @dzhioev

- А все потому, что `CyclicArray` в таком воплощении — это не `std::vector` в соответствии со стандартом ([`23.3.6.1 Class template vector overview`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf)), а, значит, наследование здесь неприменимо.

- Это значит, что перед нами принципиально другой контейнер, и должен быть реализован отдельным шаблоном типа [`boost::circular_buffer`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/circular_buffer/doc/circular_buffer.html) или, как минимум, адаптером типа `make_circular_container<Container>`.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать,

* Из С++11 еще используется наследование конструкторов

    using std::vector<T>::vector;
    
 Про constexpr: странная штука, но в векторе (судя по http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector ) нет ни одного constexpr конструктора. Как в таком случае предлагается использовать constexpr operator[]?

Comment: * При передаче в функцию по ссылке на vector все будет хорошо, т.к.:
a) operator[] не виртуальный б) если бы даже он таким и был, поведение CyclicArray::operator[] не отличается от поведения vector::operator[] на множестве аргументов допустимых для использования в vector::operator[]. Единственная проблема -- это невиртуальный деструктор в vector, поэтому удалять CyclicArray через указатель на vector нельзя.

Comment: @VladD, какие еще подводные камни в таком макросе? (ну, только имена аргументов (с _s и _res работать не будет))



    #define circind(index,size) ({ssize_t _s = (size), _res = (index) % _s; \
        if (_res < 0) _res += _s; _res;})


IMHO все очевидно. А вот как работать с неизвестно как реализованным классом это еще разбираться надо.

Более того, подобный макрос очевидным образом применим к отрезку из середины массива, а как это сделать с данным классом?

Comment: @dzhioev, я пишу на С в основном, и для поставленной задачи нет необходимости писать "простыню".

Comment: @avp: в таком макросе подводных камней больше не вижу. Но он нетривиален. И автор ответа ошибся, когда писал свой вариант. Думаете, всякий разработчик понимает, для чего нужны локальные переменные? Думаете, никто для «оптимизации» не уберёт эти переменные?

Мне кажется, макросы-блоки в gcc не от хорошей жизни.

Comment: @VladD, спасибо, учту на будущее.

Comment: @VladD, в большинстве случаев, конечно, вместо макросов лучше писать в .h короткие `static inline` функции. 

Все-таки обычно (я **не про** традиционные системные .h) макросы пишут "контекстно-зависимые", т.е. для "сжатия" кода и половина переменных там это переменные функции или модуля и стандартно повторяющиеся с ними действия, а только часть - аргументы.

--

А по поводу ошибок и нетривиальности - это еще надо посмотреть в коде на каком из языков (Си или С++) люди больше ошибаются.

Я понимаю, что ХК не может быть индикатором, но посмотрите на соотношение вопросов по этим языкам здесь.

Comment: @avp: насчёт `inline`-функций всецело одобряю, потери производительности с современными оптимизирующими компиляторами быть не должно, а неприятных сюрпризов на много порядков меньше.

Comment: Современный C++ все больше становится сложностью, ложно принимаемой за глубину